# Simple substr and strlen question...I'm going crazy

Tags: php, substr, strlen

Ok, so looking at this code:

```
$accountMask = substr($transaction['cc_number'], strlen($transaction['cc_number'])-4);
```

I think it takes a number like this:  **1234567890**
And turns it into this: **123456**

Am I crazy to think that the code is actually doing this: **7890** ??

In my opinion, if I wanted to show just the last 4 digits of a number like a CC number, I would do this:

```
$accountMask = substr($transaction['cc_number'], -4);
```

Right?

Comment: read the documentation for `substr()`....

Comment: what are you even asking? the second method is the most fool proof way of getting the last 4 digits of the card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your examples do the same thing. As per the comments check out the documentation on [substr()](http://php.net/substr)

Particularly the second parameter:

> If start is non-negative, the
>   returned string will start at the
>   start'th position in string, counting
>   from zero. For instance, in the string
>   'abcdef', the character at position 0
>   is 'a', the character at position 2 is
>   'c', and so forth.
>
> If start is negative, the returned
>   string will start at the start'th
>   character from the end of string.
>
> If string is less than or equal to
>   start characters long, FALSE will be
>   returned.

Answer (score 0):

> string substr ( string $string , int
>   $start [, int $length ] )
>
> Returns the portion of string
>   specified by the start and length
>   parameters.

To get what you want, specify $start=0, i.e. use:

```
$accountMask = substr($transaction['cc_number'], 0, -4);
```

Or:

```
$accountMask = substr($transaction['cc_number'], 0, strlen($transaction['cc_number'])-4);
```

You could read more about `substr()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

Definition of [`substr()`](http://us.php.net/substr):

`string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )`

Your code is setting `$accountMask` to the last 4 numbers of `$transaction['cc_number']`

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the `substr` function is

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

per [here](https://www.php.net/substr).

So you're passing in the string and the position to start at. It takes everything after that. If you wanted it to do what you said it looks like, you'd want to call it like this:

```
$accountMask = substr($transaction['cc_number'], 0, strlen($transaction['cc_number'])-4);
```